# Next JS - Meta Tags Missing in Source Code

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, meta-tags

I have installed multiple meta tags such as title, description, keywords, etc.

However it is not showing these tags in view source. Therefore Facebook sharing cards are not working (I have installed `og` tags but they seem no where to be found on Facebook's **Scraper** or my view source. However it is populate on Client Slide.

My Head Format (Show Tags in Client Inspect / DevTools but not in View Source):

```
import Head from 'next/head';

export default () => (
  <>
    <Head>
      <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
      <meta property="og:url" content={url} />
    </Head>
    <Header />
    <Body />
    <Footer />
  </>
)
```

Output (Redacted Page Props):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style data-next-hide-fouc="true">body{display:none}</style><noscript data-next-hide-fouc="true"><style>body{display:block}</style></noscript><meta charSet="utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/><meta name="next-head-count" content="2"/><link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/development/pages/_app.js?ts=1592258092029" as="script"/><link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/development/pages/Home.js?ts=1592258092029" as="script"/><link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/runtime/webpack.js?ts=1592258092029" as="script"/><link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/runtime/main.js?ts=1592258092029" as="script"/><noscript id="__next_css__DO_NOT_USE__"></noscript></head><body><div id="__next"></div><script src="/_next/static/runtime/react-refresh.js?ts=1592258092029"></script><script src="/_next/static/development/dll/dll_f9de5cbc314a1e41f91e.js?ts=1592258092029"></script><script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">{"props":{"pageProps": "page":"/Home","query":{},"buildId":"development","isFallback":false,"gssp":true}</script><script nomodule="" src="/_next/static/runtime/polyfills.js?ts=1592258092029"></script><script async="" data-next-page="/_app" src="/_next/static/development/pages/_app.js?ts=1592258092029"></script><script async="" data-next-page="/Home" src="/_next/static/development/pages/Home.js?ts=1592258092029"></script><script src="/_next/static/runtime/webpack.js?ts=1592258092029" async=""></script><script src="/_next/static/runtime/main.js?ts=1592258092029" async=""></script><script src="/_next/static/development/_buildManifest.js?ts=1592258092029" async=""></script><script src="/_next/static/development/_ssgManifest.js?ts=1592258092029" async=""></script></body></html>
```

Comment: From your code snippet, you are not passing `title` and `url` from props, you probably missed out here but not in the real code though.

Comment: @Hangindev Yes, I have included them all in the real code. However, Facebook's scrapping doesnt really work

Comment: The output in the question is captured during development? How about the output in production?

Comment: @Hangindev The output is generally the same in production as well.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could produce a minimal, reproducible example with [CodeSandbox's Next.js Template](https://codesandbox.io/s/1y99m5k27j).

Comment: @Hangindev I've just found out that its due to Redux Persist, Redux Persist disables SSR server side. Disabling it server side, seems to do the trick! Thank for your help! Much appreciated

Comment: @LaveshDeepakPanjwani have you solved this issue ? i am facing the same issue can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to be from Redux Persist which disables SSR. Disabling PersistGate server side seems to fix the issue.

[Github Issue Link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8240)

```
return process.browser ? (
        <PersistGate persistor={store.__persistor} loading={<div>Loading</div>}>
            <ToastProvider>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </ToastProvider>
        </PersistGate>
    ) : (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ToastProvider>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </ToastProvider>
            </Provider>
        );
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me!

Comment: This won't work with next.js dev because it alters the tree. I'll probably just add the https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/src/integration/react.ts logic to my app without touching the hierarchy.